# How to bind a Store using Spring Cloud Stream and Kafka?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'd like to use a Kafka state store of type **KeyValueStore** in a sample application using the Kafka Binder of Spring Cloud Stream.
According to the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_state_store), it should be pretty simple.
This is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaStreamTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaStreamTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public BiFunction<KStream<String, String>, KeyValueStore<String,String>, KStream<String, String>> process(){
        return (input,store) -> input.mapValues(v -> v.toUpperCase());

    }


    @Bean
    public StoreBuilder myStore() {
        return Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
                Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("my-store"), Serdes.String(),
                Serdes.String());
    }
}
```

I suppose that the KeyValueStore should be passed as the second parameter of the "process" method, but the application fails to start with the message below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory found for binding target type: org.apache.kafka.streams.state.KeyValueStore among registered factories: channelFactory,messageSourceFactory,kStreamBoundElementFactory,kTableBoundElementFactory,globalKTableBoundElementFactory
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.getBindingTargetFactory(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:82) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.function.KafkaStreamsBindableProxyFactory.bindInput(KafkaStreamsBindableProxyFactory.java:191) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.function.KafkaStreamsBindableProxyFactory.afterPropertiesSet(KafkaStreamsBindableProxyFactory.java:103) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution about how to use a store reading an [unit test](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/function/KafkaStreamsFunctionStateStoreTests.java) in Spring Cloud Stream.

The code below is how I applied that solution to my code.
The transformer uses the Store provided by Spring bean method "*myStore*"

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaStreamTestApplication {

    public static final String MY_STORE_NAME = "my-store";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaStreamTestApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> process2(){
        return (input) -> input.
              transformValues(() -> new MyValueTransformer(), MY_STORE_NAME);

    }


    @Bean
    public StoreBuilder<?> myStore() {
        return Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
                Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(MY_STORE_NAME), Serdes.String(),
                Serdes.String());
    }

}
```

```
public class MyValueTransformer implements ValueTransformer<String, String> {

    private KeyValueStore<String,String> store;
    private ProcessorContext context;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        store = (KeyValueStore<String, String>) this.context.getStateStore(KafkaStreamTestApplication.MY_STORE_NAME);

    }

    @Override
    public String transform(String value) {
        String tValue = store.get(value);

        if(tValue==null) {
            store.put(value, value.toUpperCase());
        }

        return tValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        if(store!=null) {
            store.close();
        }
    }

}
```